# Calling an xsl template from another xsl file not working

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to call an xsl template from another xsl file and to store the value of template in a variable. I have 2 xsl files: File1.xsl and File2.xsl
In File2.xsl, I have defined an xsl template like

```
<xsl:template name="template1" >
        <xsl:param name="param1" />
        <xsl:param name="param2" />
        <xsl:param name="param3" />     
        <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when....
                    <xsl:value-of select="$param1"/>    
                    </xsl:when>
                    ......
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am calling this xsl template present in File2.xsl in File1.xsl. I have imported File2.xsl in File1.xsl. Also I am trying to store the value returned from the template in a variable for further processing as below.

In File1.xsl:

```
<xsl:variable name="Result" >
        <xsl:call-template name="template1">
            <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="$param1" />
            <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="$param2" />
            <xsl:with-param name="param3" select="$param3" />
        </xsl:call-template>    
</xsl:variable>
```

But I am not getting the value in the Result variable as expected($Result). Is anything wrong in my logic or syntax?

Comment: Post a minimal but complete, executable snippet of XSLT with the relevant minimal but complete XML input data, to allow us to reproduce the problem. Also explain which result exactly you expect and which one or which error you get instead.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. (So there must be something wrong with the code you haven't shown us.)

Comment: To understand your issue, we need to know: How your <xsl:import href=""/> looks like? What conditions in <xsl:choose> block in File2.xsl (cause it is possible that it is simply did not pass conditions)? And finally in File1.xsl, when you are calling template and passing parameters what is inside $param1,$param2 and $param3 variables/parameters (as we see only that you are passing it)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. This issue has been fixed. The problem was that I was loading a value from the xml file to the variable in xsl and this value contains a trailing space which made my condition to fail. There was nothing wrong with the code. After removing the trailing space the code was good to go. Thanks everyone for the valuable replies.